# Converter tipo timefield do Ext JS para time no DB

Tags: php, javascript, java, extjs

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
var finalTime = record.get('attendance_time'); //Recupera valor do attendance_time
record.set('attendance_time',finalTime.toTimeString());
```

Nesse código eu pego o valor de um campo *timefield* e uso um método do próprio ext JS para converter ele pra um formato que a minha coluna no db do tipo time aceite. Porem quando eu coloco esse método(*toTimeString*) e seto ele no valor da array que antes tinha a campo não convertido, ele fica *undefined*.

Quero saber se estou utilizando o método certo e se estiver porque ele está ficando com *undefined* apos setar.

Answer (score 0):

nao entendi bem sua pergunta, mas acho que em todo caso vc tem que colocar o resultado da sugunda linha de codigo em uma variavel

```
var finalTime = record.get('attendance_time'); //Recupera valor do attendance_time
//variavel final_time 
var final_time = record.set('attendance_time',finalTime.toTimeString());
```

```
record.data.attendance_time = finalTime; 
record.markDirty();
```

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta pra ver se melhoro o entendimento

Comment: Editei, verifica se deu pra entender por favor.

Comment: antes de conveter o valor com toTimeString, vc testo que o valor ja nao seja indefinido?
Ouseja finalTime depois da primeira linha de codigo tem um valor o ja è indefinida?

Comment: Antes de converter com o toTimeString ele possui valor! Quando eu converto e seto ele da undefined, deve ser alguma coisa ao setar, pois ele não esta setando nada, nem q eu coloquei outro coisa para setar, acho q o valor está sendo convertido, porem o problema é na hora de setar.

Answer (score -3):

Caso esteja utilizando a toolkit **classic** você pode alterar o formato que os dados serão enviados para seu backend diretamente no field, utilizando a propriedade [submitFormat](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Time.html#cfg-submitFormat), criei um fiddle com um exemplo de uso:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3hja

Você pode personalizar como quiser o valor do submit, usando o template (valores) padrões, segue link como referencia [Ext.Date#property-defaults](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.Date.html#property-defaults)